# How to use loops for categories in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Hi all here i am having few set of values i want to show all of them in one single graph using Highcharts.js Now i have hardcoded the values if i want to push the values How can it be done

```
enter code here
data set -1 
        "data_set": [{"y": 4.188145161290322, "x": "2016-01-13 04:54:01.594091"}, {"y": 4.292354838709678, "x": "2016-01-13 06:09:25.834223"}]

 data-set-2 

enter code here
 "data_set": [{"y": 25145.715, "x": "2016-01-13 04:55:30.057155"}, {"y": 25478.8025, "x": "2016-01-13 06:11:03.849181"}]
```

this is what i have done

http://jsfiddle.net/Goutham_Pratapa/4xtsjbn6/2/
thanks in advance

Comment: You don't have to manually set categories. Instead you can set type of xAxis to `category`, then simply each of your points should have `name` property which will be used as category. Here is a sample for you: http://jsfiddle.net/4xtsjbn6/6/ - I used `map` (kind of for-loop) which returns new object with Highcharts-expected format.

Answer (score 1):

You replace these lines

```
    "data_set": [{"y": 4.188145161290322, "x": "2016-01-13 04:54:01.594091"}, {"y": 4.292354838709678, "x": "2016-01-13 06:09:25.834223"}]
```

With string variables

```
    "data_set": [{"y": stringY1, "x": stringX1}, {"y": stringY2, "x": stringX2}]
```

Just initialize the variables somewhere else in your program

Comment: i want the same graph with loops instead of hardcoding
 http://jsfiddle.net/Goutham_Pratapa/4xtsjbn6/4/ this is wat i have done till now couldnt proceed further

Comment: Can you clarify how you want to use loops? If you use variables, you can assign their values elsewhere in the program -- maybe via user input or taking the data from somewhere else in your program.

Comment: please see this fiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/Goutham_Pratapa/4xtsjbn6/4/ 
u can understand i want to write a for loop and generate graph by calling the values from the data set

Comment: Did you figure it out? I just looked at your jsfiddle and it looks like you have it working the way you wanted it to

Comment: Sorry @Ethan Fischer i updated the fiddle i will figure it out
http://jsfiddle.net/Goutham_Pratapa/4xtsjbn6/2/ this is a hardcode values fiddle if u obser i used categories and series thrice in future if i have five or more instead of writing it there hardcoded how to write them in a loop if i have a data set that was my question sorry for the trouble